# Splitting a string in reverse order

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
sub_string="CDC"
rstring=[ sub_string[-i] for i in range(len(sub_string))]

print(rstring)
```

when I print the rstring it gives the output `['C', 'C', 'D']`

in this list the letters are sorted automatically I don't want them to be sorted

how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not being sorted:

```py
sub_string="CDC"
rstring=[]

for i in range(len(sub_string)):
    print(f"{sub_string[-i]=}, {-i=}")
    rstring.append(sub_string[-i])

print(rstring)
```

Output

```
sub_string[-i]='C', -i=0
sub_string[-i]='C', -i=-1
sub_string[-i]='D', -i=-2
['C', 'C', 'D']
```

If you know how negative index works you'll see what's going on.

You're grabbing the first letter, the last letter and the second to last letter.

Output for 12345 so it's easier to see:

```
sub_string[-i]='1', -i=0
sub_string[-i]='5', -i=-1
sub_string[-i]='4', -i=-2
sub_string[-i]='3', -i=-3
sub_string[-i]='2', -i=-4
['1', '5', '4', '3', '2']
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that strings in python are iterable, so `sub_string[::-1]` also reverses the string

Answer (score 0):

Now the `range()` iterates from `0` to `len(sub_string) - 1` (included). So the first iteration gets first character, the second last character and third the middle `D`.

Iterate from `1` to `len(sub_string)` (included) instead:

```py
sub_string = "CDC"
rstring = [sub_string[-i] for i in range(1, len(sub_string) + 1)]

print(rstring)
```

Prints:

```
['C', 'D', 'C']
```

---

Note: The same you can do for example with `list(reversed(sub_string))`